# What kind/model is this frame?

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

Can someone help me what kind of alpinestars bike frame is this, and where it is manufactured? Just got it a year ago.. I've already search alpinestars website but couldn't find this exact frame.. 
Here is the bike's serial number JYW16047461

[image]

Comment: Where did you get it from? Maybe they know.

Comment: What's the word on the fork stanchion (the white on silver) Can't read it.

Comment: in our local bike shop here in manila it actually comes with 2 colors and one of them was black and silver... that's only a decal that fork was rst omega series i just customized it and put some nofx logo on the lowers..

Answer (score 1):

Alpinestars hasn't made bikes since around 1996. This is definitely not one of their 90's frames. That being said they do sponsor mountain bike teams and make clothing and gear. It is not unheard of for these companies to get lower end frames from the manufactures of the brands their teams ride and have them branded for them. My guess is that is what this frame is.

Comment: i will go on your answer on this one.i actually thinking the same thing bout this frame.. . I've emailed alpinestars customer service they actualy said the same thing about not making any frames since early 90's.. and said that this frame didn't came from them.. so i ask him is it fake or what.? then replied that they wouldn't want to make that claim, but it is possible...  thanks john./